# Second UITabBar

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I already looking since a hour for a solution of my problem. 
A picture can tell more then thousand words:

[image: second tabbar]

I have two TabBars in my ViewController. The first one I created with the storyboard, and it works. Now I would like to have the second one to select the type of connection. Because every connection type has some own things to fill. I just drag and drop a new UITabTab into my ViewController, added a third TabBar item but I don't know what is next. How to handle the second TabBar. What methods do I need? How to catch touches on this items, so I can change a view?

Comment: This isn't what you want. Use a Toolbar or a custom `UIView`

Comment: I already tried Toolbar, but it doesn't look as good as UITabBar.

Comment: You will want to use a `UISegmentedControl` for that. Apple does not like nested `UITabBar`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a UITabBarViewController or a UIViewController? I suspect the first is the case and you don't know how to hook up two of the same to one ViewController. What you need to do is to take apart the delegate methods for the UITabBar so you can do it twice in the same controller.

You should do the following:

- Use a regular UIViewController
- Drag two UITabBars onto the View
- Connect them to your ViewController
- Create two implementations of the UITabBarDelegate for each UITabBar in separate classes
- At viewDidLoad or a similar event create instances of those classes and set the "delegate" of each UITabBar to that instance

## Some example code

First create a new class for the bar on top. It only needs to do one thing:

```
#import "LVDTopTabDelegate.h"

@implementation LVDTopTabDelegate

// This is the only required part of the delegate
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item;
{
    // Handle what you wanted to do
}

@end
```

The second one is more or less the same

```
#import "LVDBottomTabDelegate.h"

@implementation LVDBottomTabDelegate

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item;
{
    // Handle what you wanted to do
}

@end
```

You viewDidLoad should look approximately like this:

```
@implementation LVDViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad;
{
    LVDTopTabDelegate *topTabDelegate = [[LVDTopTabDelegate alloc] init];
    self.topTabBar.delegate = topTabDelegate; // self.topTabBar is an IBOutlet for your tab bar
    
    LVDBottomTabDelegate *topTabDelegate = [[LVDBottomTabDelegate alloc] init];
    self.bottomTabBar.delegate = bottomTabDelegate;
}

@end
```

Comment: OK, now I understand. I though it should be some IBAction or so, but delegate. Thank you.

Comment: Nowadays I barely use anything else than the default UIViewController because it's cleaner to separate all the delegates and you're way more flexible if you want to change or style things. Except for Container View Controllers.